# Loop interrompe o script, mas não dá erro

Tags: php, mysql, loop

Estou montando uma lista que recolhe dados de usuários. Como alguns dados estão em tabelas diferentes (a de anexos, precisamente) eu montei uma *query select* para captar só aqueles anexos que tenham a mesma `id` de usuário (tabela que chamei de `attach_user_id` previamente já alimentada pelo formulário) e joguei numa variável para poder imprimir de dentro do *loop* que faz a consulta na tabela alunos. O script faz exatamente o que eu quero, ou melhor, quase. A lista é impressa, formatada, tudo ok MAS a página é cortada e o script não passa da última linha da tabela, ou seja, nem carrega o footer. Não consigo entender onde estou errando, e o script não retorna nenhum erro.

Onde estou errando?

```
<?php // o erro esta daqui em diante
while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($users) or die(mysqli_error($sql_con)))
{
    $user_id = $user['id'];
    $user_attachments = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT attach_name,attach_path,attach_user_id FROM " . ATTACHMENTS_TABLE . " WHERE attach_user_id LIKE '$user_id'") or die(mysqli_error($sql_con));
    $docs = mysqli_fetch_array($user_attachments);
        ?><tr>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['nome'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['dia'] . " de " . str_replace_assoc($mes,$user['mes']) . " de " . $user['ano']; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['curso'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['unidade'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['endereco'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['bairro'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['cep'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['numero'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['rg'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['cpf'] . "  " ; ?></font></td>
            <td align='center'><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><a href='<?php echo $docs['attach_path'] . $docs['attach_name']; ?>'><img src='doc.png' alt='Ver documento anexado' style='width:16px;height:20px;'></a></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['email'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['telefone'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['celular'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
            <td><font face='Calibri' size='2' color='#888888'><?php echo $user['site'] . "  "; ?></font></td>
        </tr><!-- a pagina so e impressa ate exatamente neste ponto -->
<?php } ?>
</table>
<hr />
<script type="text/javascript">
function voltar()
{
         location.href="form.php"
}
function lista()
{
         location.href="lista.php"
}
</script>
<p align="center"><button onclick="lista()">Recarregar lista</button> <button onclick="voltar()">Novo cadastro</button></p>
<br/><br/>
<?php INCLUDE('./footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: A linha `hr` é impressa?

Comment: Não é não, só é impressa até imediatamente chegar a última tag do while, eu comentei ali no código

Comment: ele retorna apenas um unico usuario, ou faz um loop com varios usuários, e para aonde vc indicou depois de listar tudo?? E o q tem antes do while??

Ja pensou em tentar resolver isso com uma unica consulta ultizando Inner Join, ou Left Join no SQL em vez de fazer um loop com outras consultas só para pegar 1 unico dado de outra tabela??

Comment: Isso que é mais estranho, ele chega a fazer o loop, lista todos os cadastros como esperado, aponta onde os arquivos estão mas não carrega o footer, nem mesmo as outras tags html depois do loop.. eu tenho certeza que a falha tá dentro do loop porque isso começou só depois que resolvi colocar os anexos no cadastro..antes do while só tem o cabeçalho html da tabela e as outras strings das querys referentes as tabelas de alunos e anexos, ali no while só tem a query que une os dados dessas consultas

Comment: tenta tirar o `die(mysqli_error($sql_con)` do seu código, e ve se mesmo assim não aparece o final. Talvez o script pode estar tendo um erro no final do look, e o die pode estar finalizando mas sem mostrar o erro na tela. O esquema é vc ir debugando linha por linha até achar o erro. Pela parte do código q vc postou, aparentemente não existe erro. Tem q verificar o q os selects estão retornando, para ver se não esta vindo nenhuma linha vazia, q possa estar retornando o erro dentro do loop.

Comment: ... e verificar se a opção de mostrar erros tanto do php, quanto do mysql estão habilitadas...

Comment: MagicHat, estão ativos, pelo menos eu já tive vários erros desde o começo da criação desse site.

Comment: Fernando VR, retirei a die() e fiz a checagem do loop com um if mesmo. Você acertou em cheio, isso resolveu o problema. Se eu soubesse que era isso, não teria esquentado tanto a cabeça, já que planejava fazer isto assim que resolvesse o problema. Muito obrigado a todos!